# Chart.js - Where do I find which components should be registered?

Tags: chart.js, chart.js3

I'm new to Chart.js, saw the v3 doc:

> Chart.js 3 is tree-shakeable, so it is necessary to import and register the controllers, elements, scales, and plugins you are going to use.

I'm wondering where do I find these things for registering, for example, what needs to be registered for [this example](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/next/getting-started/usage) to work?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You will get an error in your console if you use something that is not imported. If you want to be sure you just have everything and throw away the benefit of tree-shaking you can use this import and register:

```js
import { Chart, registerables } from 'chart.js'

Chart.register(...registerables)
```

Or in one line:

```js
import Chart from 'chart.js/auto'
```

For the example to work, the elements that need to be imported and registered are:

- `barController`
- `barElement`
- `categoryScale`
- `Tooltip`
- `Legend`

Generally speaking for a chart you need its **controller** so `lineController` for line chart, `pieController` for a pie chart, etc.
You need the **element** so a `lineElement` and `pointElement` for line or radar chart, `arcElement` for pie, doughnut or polar area chart, and `barElement` for bar chart.
And then you need to import the supplied **plugins** for the title, filler (for area charts), legend, and the tooltip.

Comment: I got errors for the Line / Scale Controllers and Elements, however it wasn't until this comment that I realised that I need to import Title, Legend and Tooltip, and that was why those were not working for me.

Answer (score 14):

Maybe is a little late, but if you are using npm, you can register everything from chart.js using

```
import { Chart, registerables } from 'chart.js';
Chart.register(...registerables);
```

Or, directly:

```
import Chart from 'chart.js/auto';
```

Also, you can see here everything it can be imported for an especific chart, and my answer above:
https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/getting-started/integration.html#bundlers-webpack-rollup-etc

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me.

```
import { Chart } from "chart.js";
import * as Chartjs from "chart.js";

const controllers = Object.values(Chartjs).filter(
  (chart) => chart.id !== undefined
);

Chart.register(...controllers);
```