# Get Chart.js to work with ImportMap in Rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, chart.js, import-maps

I tried:

```
./bin/importmap pin chart.js
```

which added this to config/importmap.rb

```
pin "chart.js", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:chart.js@3.9.1/dist/chart.mjs"
```

In application.js I added:

```
import 'chart.js'
```

When I try to create a new Chart I get "Chart is not defined".

If I try

```
import Chart from 'chart.js'
```

I get "The requested module 'chart.js' does not provide an export named 'default'"

```
import Chart from 'chart.js/auto'
```

says "Failed to resolve module specifier 'chart.js/auto'"

Comment: Same problem here... Did you find a fix?

Comment: No, I avoided using chart.js for the project.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same struggle this weekend and kept happening upon this article, so posting my solution here.

A couple things of note:

1. Chart.js seems to have some hardcoded accessory files that aren't registered as dependencies in the CDN. For example, mine kept 404ing on *c1719c72.js* and *chunks/helpers.segment.js*. For this reason, it works better if you don't use the *--download* flag when running `bin/importmap pin`. Credit to this article: [Using chart.js with importmaps in rail 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72500076/using-chart-js-with-importmaps-in-rail-7).
2. Importing Chart from chart.js requires a little magic from here: [Chart.js - Where do I find which components should be registered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65002923/chart-js-where-do-i-find-which-components-should-be-registered). Specifically, lines 3-4 of barchart_controller.js below.

### **Here's a summary of the file contents that worked for me on a fairly plain Rails 7 build with importmaps:**

`config/importmap.rb` - Note: Running `bin/importmap pin chart.js` should pull in one dependency (@kurkle/color). Be sure to skip --download, or you're in for a world of pain.

```
# Pin npm packages by running ./bin/importmap

pin "application", preload: true
pin "@hotwired/turbo-rails", to: "turbo.min.js", preload: true
pin "@hotwired/stimulus", to: "stimulus.min.js", preload: true
pin "@hotwired/stimulus-loading", to: "stimulus-loading.js", preload: true
pin_all_from "app/javascript/controllers", under: "controllers"

pin "chart.js", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:chart.js@4.2.0/dist/chart.js"
pin "@kurkle/color", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:@kurkle/color@0.3.2/dist/color.esm.js"
```

---

`app/javascript/application.js`

```
// Configure your import map in config/importmap.rb. Read more: https://github.com/rails/importmap-rails
import "@hotwired/turbo-rails"
import "controllers"

import "chart.js"
```

---

`app/javascript/controllers/barchart_controller.js`

```
import {Controller} from "@hotwired/stimulus"

import { Chart, registerables } from "chart.js";
Chart.register(...registerables);

export default class extends Controller {
    static targets = ['myChart'];

    canvasContext() {
        return this.myChartTarget.getContext('2d');
    }

    connect() {
        new Chart(this.canvasContext(), {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
                datasets: [{
                    label: '# of Votes',
                    data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
                    backgroundColor: [
                        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                    ],
                    borderColor: [
                        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                    ],
                    borderWidth: 1
                }]
            },
            options: {
                scales: {
                    y: {
                        beginAtZero: true
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

---

Content from the div in my model's `app/views/widgets/show.html.erb`

```
<div data-controller="barchart">
  <canvas id="bar-chart" data-barchart-target="myChart" width="800" height="450"></canvas>
</div>
```

Don't forget to rebuild assets (bin/rails assets:precompile).

Comment: I'm assuming your answer works cause it looks good. Thanks for documenting this for others.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I got it to work on a rails 7 app with importmaps.

```
const { Chart, registerables } = await import('chart.js');
Chart.register(...registerables);
```